# I have a varchar value 1st March 2017 that i need as a date 01-MAR-2017 in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

SELECT TO_DATE('1st March 2017','DD MON YYYY')   from dual

It's ok with SELECT TO_DATE(01 March 2017','DD MON YYYY')   from dual , doesn't like the 'st'

Comment: You don't need [PL/SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/plsql/info) for this. You can do it with a plain query.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like regex:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(
    regexp_replace('1st March 2017','^(\d+)\w+','\1')
,'DD MON YYYY') from dual
```

Answer (score 1):

Alas, you can't do it directly: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#BABGDDFB

**Notes on date format element suffixes:**

- When you add one of these suffixes to a datetime format element, the return value is always in English.
- **Datetime suffixes are valid only to format output. You cannot use them to insert a date into the database.**

Which actually means they work only with `to_char()` to transform a date into a string; they don't work with `to_date()` to convert a string to a date.

So you will have to play dirty tricks - perhaps regexp_replace to get rid of `st`. Like Michael has shown already.

Answer (score 0):

Hope here is your answer

```
SELECT to_date('1st march 2017','dd"st" month yyyy') "Date" FROM dual;
```

### Date

01-MAR-17

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(to_date('1st march 2017','dd"st" month yyyy'),'dd-mon-yyyy') "Date"
FROM dual;
```

### Date

01-mar-2017

Comment: This solution works for the specific input string, but presumably there may be more strings in the table (or wherever the first string came from) - and they may have 22nd or 3rd or 11th...  so just "st" won't do.